# R: What can I do about a slow double sapply?

Tags: r, sapply

I have a computation that does a version of this:

```
n <- 5
l <- 3
m <- seq(0,1,length.out = n)
r <- seq(3,4,length.out = n)
y <- 1:n

pp <- sapply(0:l, function(h) cumsum(y[(h+1):n]*y[1:(n-h)]))
rec.acf <- sapply(0:l, function(h) pp[[h+1]] + sapply((h+1):n, function(j) m[j] + r[j-h]) )
```

to obtain

```
> rec.acf
[[1]]
[1]  4.0  8.5 18.0 34.5 60.0

[[2]]
[1]  5.25 11.75 24.25 44.75

[[3]]
[1]  6.5 15.0 30.5

[[4]]
[1]  7.75 18.25
```

In practice, of course, `n` and `l` are much larger (and the actual functions, [computing autocovariances](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/acf.html) over samples of increasing size, are more complicated).

When `l` is relatively small, as I had hoped for, the computations work much faster than other implementations I had worked out that do not take into account that I can recycle many identical computations through `pp`.

However, the picture reverses when `l` is large relative to `n`, likely because the outer `sapply` then sends off many inner loops. Is there anything obviously inefficient about my approach?

I tinkered with `mapply`, without much success.

Comment: Personally, I would write out an R version with explicit `for` loops and then translate it to C++ using Rcpp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner loop is unnecessary:

```
mm = lapply(0:l, function(h) tail(m, length(m) - h) + head(r, length(r) - h))

mapply("+", pp, mm)
#[[1]]
#[1]  4.0  8.5 18.0 34.5 60.0
#
#[[2]]
#[1]  5.25 11.75 24.25 44.75
#
#[[3]]
#[1]  6.5 15.0 30.5
#
#[[4]]
#[1]  7.75 18.25
```

Comment: Run only one `sapply` call: `sapply(0:l, function(h) tail(m, length(m) - h) + cumsum(y[(h+1):n]*y[1:(n-h)]))`

Comment: I thank you for your +1 answers/comments and apologize for having oversimplified my reprex - I made an edit that reflects more closely my actual problem and (at least to me) makes avoiding the inner loop less obvious.

Comment: @ChristophHanck that's still just as simple of an expression - see edit